# Play framework 2.0 scala form error handling

Tags: forms, scala, playframework-2.0

I have a problem with form , the problem is that I can't show error in view properly(I think so). Validation works fine.

When the old password is incorrect error message is displayed below input box on the other hand when passwords are mismatched error isn't appearing anywhere.

If I do some debug I get data:

from in view:
  `@pass_form("password").errors`

I get this:

```
FormError(password,Passwords dont match,WrappedArray())
```

So my question how to fix form or code in view, to print that error properly.

```
Form(
    mapping(
        "old_password" -> text.verifying(Messages("forms.password.old.mismatch"),
        password => User.correct_?(user.id, password)),
       "password" -> tuple(
       "new" -> text(minLength = conf.getInt("password.length.min").get),
       "confirm" -> text).verifying(Messages("forms.password.new.mismatch"), 
          passwords => passwords._1 == passwords._2)
      )
    ((_, password) => password._1)((_) => Some(("", ("", ""))))
         )
```

In view I have:

```
@helper.form(action = routes.UserController.submitPassword) {

        @helper.input(pass_form("old_password")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
            <input type="password" name="@name" id="@id" @toHtmlArgs(args)>  
        }

        @helper.input(pass_form("password.new")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
            <input type="password" name="@name" id="@id" @toHtmlArgs(args)>  
        }

        @helper.input(pass_form("password.confirm")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
            <input type="password" name="@name" id="@id" @toHtmlArgs(args)>  
        }

        <input type="submit" value="Set">
    }
```

Comment: It may be a dump question but how do you get `user.id` in your form ?

Comment: I use a module from https://github.com/t2v/play20-auth and there is a method called authorizedAction and it give me a user.

Comment: Thank you i will check that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you might want to use the helper method for your password fields, since there is one for them. Have a look at `views.html.helper.inputPassword` and use it like so:

```
@helper.inputPassword(field = pass_form("old_password"))
```

The reason why the *Passwords don't match* error is not displayed is, that it is an error bound to the form itself and not to a specific field. You will have to check the `errors` field of your form for that, which will give you a `Seq[FormError]`. You can then display these in an appropriate manner...

Best regards

Comment: Thx for help but inputPassword work strange, when password update didn't succeed I get form with filled value.

My soltion is: @helper.input(pass_form("old_password"),'_error->pass_form("old_password").error)